# Stop AngularJS ng-repeat rendering in alphabetical order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my angular app I'm trying to display JSON data in a table. The data looks like this:

```
$scope.data = 
  {
    "EVENT NAME":"Free Event",
    "ORDER ID":311575707,
    "DATE":"6/26/14",
    "GROSS REVENUE (USD)":"0",
    "TICKET REVENUE (USD)":"0",
    "EVENTBRITE FEES (USD)":"0",
    "CC PROCESSING (USD)":"0",
    "TICKETS":1,
    "TYPE":"Free Order",
    "STATUS":"Free Order",
    "TRANSACTION ID":"",
    "NOTES":"",
    "FIRST NAME":"Khee Seng",
    "LAST NAME":"Chua",
    "EMAIL ADDRESS":"email@anemailadderss.com"
  };
```

And I'm displaying it like this:

```
   <table class="table table-striped selector">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
            <strong>{{key}}</strong>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
                    {{value}}
                </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

In my mind this should go through each `(key, value) pair in the object and display it in order. However, AngularJS displays the values in alphabetical order.

Here's a plunkr which replicates this issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/V3Y2ZuwV1v9Pzsl0jGhA?p=preview

**How can I tweak the code so it displays in the natural order that the object actually comes in?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve it like this

**[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/GmBOAVHofusbEvWdLC2i?p=preview)**

In the scope define a method like as shown

```
$scope.notSorted = function(obj){
    if (!obj) {
        return [];
    }
    return Object.keys(obj);
}
```

and in html like as shown below

**html**

```
<table class="table table-striped selector">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="key in notSorted(data)">
         {{key}}
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td ng-repeat="key in notSorted(data)" ng-init="value = data[key]">
            {{value}}
         </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Original Article: **[ng-repeat with no sort? How?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/N87uqMfwcTs)**

Comment: Great, this is my preferred solution as it let me keep the structure of the objects that are being passed in.

Answer (score 5):

A Javascript object does not have the concept of 'natural order' of its keys:

Definition of an Object from ECMAScript Third Edition ([here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf)):

> 4.3.3 Object
>   An object is a member of the type Object. It is an unordered collection of properties
>   each of which contains a primitive value, object, or function [...]

You probably should change a bit your data structure...
For example:

```
$scope.data = 
{
    1: { "EVENT NAME": "Free Event" },
    2: { "ORDER ID": 311575707 },
    /* ... */
};
```

And then use the numerical key to sort your items...

Comment: your object is probably cleaner than mine :)

Comment: identifying the problem is what really matters... :-)

Comment: There's no substitute for properly-formed data! I restructured mine after reading through this and realizing that I'd kludged it up.

Answer (score 2):

Object properties don't have a **natural order**.

You can achieve what you're looking for with a slightly different Object:

```
$scope.data = 
  {
    columns: [
      {
        "EVENT NAME":"Free Event",
        "priority": 0        
      },
      {
        "ORDER_ID":311575707,
        "priority": 1        
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
```